# Swift UIButton image has incorrect insets when using adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I have a `UIButton` with image. When text is not scaled everything is ok. But when text started scaling with `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth`, image edge insets are ignored and every time I see my image on the random position. My code is:

```
let tintedImage = UIImage(named: icon)?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
let tintedImageHighlighted = UIImage(named: icon)?.alpha(0.7).withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)

button.setImage(soundTintedImage, for: .normal)
button.setImage(soundTintedImageHighlighted, for: .highlighted)

button.titleLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
button.titleLabel?.baselineAdjustment = .alignCenters
button.titleLabel?.minimumScaleFactor = 0.4

let imageInsets : UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(4, 18, 0, 0)
button.imageEdgeInsets = imageInsets
```

I am using auto layout and positioned `UIButton` centrally on the view and set leading and trailing constraints to let work `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth`. Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: Did you try setting the image in button's background with setBackground function?